# Save loaded HTML file from electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to explore electron and trying to make a simple Mac application. The problem is that I wanted to save the loaded HTML when user closes the application, and upon next start of application the saved html will be loaded.

Now, consider following case:
The html which i have loaded initially have some table and items, and during runtime, via javascript I am adding few new rows and values. So the html is modified at runtime. Now when user closes the app, i have to save this html (which is modified).
I tried using webContents.savePage but the page which was saved is the HTML which was loaded initially i.e. without runtime changes.
How can I do it?

Also I am not able to catch windows.onbeforeunload event, don't know why.
But window.closed is triggerd.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `File` or `Blob` object of `document`

```
let file = new File([document.documentElement.outerHTML]
           , "file-" + new Date().getTime() + ".html"
           , {type:"text/html", lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'close' Event from the BrowserWindow to prevent closing the window in the main process.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#event-close